# Git - necessary to have multiple local branches matching to remote branches?

Tags: git, version-control, github, bitbucket

I have code for a website that is ready for release in the origin/master branch.

I created a new branch on my server with `git branch` so it now returns

```
$ git branch
* develop
master
```

And Bitbucket shows that I have two branches as well - master and develop. My question is, how do I separate out the branches on my server (local branches, I believe they are called).

Do I need separate folders for each branch, or does `git checkout` automatically update everything in the folder to match the remote branch? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need multiple folders, `git checkout $BRANCH` will seamlessly switch between branches. But if you want to reflect the upstream changes you will need `git pull` or `git fetch`.

`git checkout` will only checkout the branch as it exists on your local machine. If you want to match the remote state, you will need to fetch all the references from that remote server. To update your currently checked out branch, use `git pull` which fetches and merges. You can also use `git fetch` to pull all the remote changes, but you will have to merge those changes in manually afterwards if you want your local branches to match the remote.

Comment: But Apache is serving the development files when I do checkout. Do I need to have two config files and two directories and everything?

Comment: If you are checking out ```master```, then only master files should be there, unless development has directories that are not present in master. Git does not track dirs, so in that case empty dirs may remain.

Comment: I mean, let's say I'm on master where the latest version is being served by Apache to a domain. Then I git checkout development branch, and the files change. Apache then has different files to serve, which I don't want it to do. How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you are trying to serve directly from your development environment, then you are going to have some inconsistencies as you checkout files. A example workflow would be to serve from a separate directory/server that only mirrors the master branch.